# Dynamic Serving for asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website which utilizes different urls scheme for rendering content to various devices. Desktops website is at mysite.com while the Mobile devices are redirected to m.mysite.com. Both are different asp.net website with same content mostly barring a url or two which render 500 error on mobile since there is no corresponding page.

Redirection Code ::

```
        string u = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        string path = Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
        Regex b = new Regex(@"android.+mobile|avantgo|bada\\/|blackberry|BB10|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        Regex v = new Regex(@"1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\\-(n|u)|c55\\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\\-5|g\\-mo|go(\\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\\-(m|p|t)|hei\\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\\-c|ht(c(\\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\\-|\\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\\-|e\\/|\\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\\-w|m3ga|m50\\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\\-g|qa\\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\\-[2-7]|i\\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\\-|oo|p\\-)|sdk\\/|se(c(\\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\\-|shar|sie(\\-|m)|sk\\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\\-|v\\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\\-|tdg\\-|tel(i|m)|tim\\-|t\\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\\-|m3|m5)|tx\\-9|up(\\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\\-|2|g)|yas\\-|your|zeto|zte\\-", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
        if ((b.IsMatch(u) || v.IsMatch(u.Substring(0, 4))))
        {
            if(!path.Contains("Images") && !path.Contains("news-images"))
            {
                string redirectTo = "http://m.mysite.com"+path;
                Response.Redirect(redirectTo);
            }
        }
```

My website is getting around 3 years old but still the kind of growth one expects is nowhere and I assume this might be one of the reasons for it. Therefore I plan on using Dynamic serving with one URL. Searching on the internet I couldn't find a way how to handle this is asp.net. A small demo or tutorial link to utilize this will be helpful to make the site use Dynamic Serving.

Comment: So whats the question?  I don't see a question mark (?).

Comment: Question is how to use dynamic serving in asp.net mvc. Any demo code or link will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I faced with this problem today and found the solution. If you want to using **[Dynamic serving](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving)** for mobile version of your website in `asp.net`, just add this line:

```
Response.AddHeader("Vary", "User-Agent")
```